# How to manage docker image dependencies (maintainance)

Tags: docker

Using docker, you can create images based on other images very nicely. For instance, you can make an image Java-jdk7 (based on the latest Ubuntu LTS), and based on that create images elastic-search and tomcat7 (both of which need java).

So, if I don't tag my images, I end up with the following (extract of `docker images`):

```
╔══════════════════════╦════════╦══════════════╗
║      REPOSITORY      ║  TAG   ║      ID      ║
╠══════════════════════╬════════╬══════════════╣
║ ubuntu               ║ 12.04  ║ 8dbd9e392a96 ║
║ quintenk/jdk7-oracle ║ latest ║ 8928245086f4 ║
║ quintenk/tomcat7     ║ latest ║ 995cdb2cbfa8 ║
║ quintenk/elastics    ║ latest ║ 123abc456ef2 ║
╚══════════════════════╩════════╩══════════════╝
```

Now for the question. How do/should I maintain this dependency? How do I perform maintainance one 1 image and the dependent images as well?

1. If I update my jdk image (`apt-get upgrade` for instance), I assume I do not corrupt the dependent images? However, I also assume that the dependency tree is not as you would expect any longer. [UPDATE: I've reproduced this, so see my own answer below]
2. If 1 is correct, is there some way that I can have the dependent images flag themselves as outdated, and (hopefully) have them rebuild themselves?

Or is the way to go to tag the containers with a version number, and manually rebuild and redistribute all dependencies with increased version number tags? That would mean the Dockerfiles would need to be altered for an update.

UPDATE:
I found the following image on the docker site in their [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/dotCloud/why-docker?ref=http://www.docker.io/about/). However, I'm not quite sure on the steps of how to do this (especially with dependencies on other images as I described).

[image: Update flow for docker containers]

Comment: Is http://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#repository-links the solution you want? It re-build all depending images if change being made at their base images.

Comment: @WeiChing indeed - that would be the new answer. Of course - this is a bad thing without automated testing

Answer (score 9):

This is a great use case. Please submit an enhancement request on the [Docker issues page](http://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues).

A simple way for now is to maintain the Dockerfiles and update from there, rebuilding the images when you want to make a deliberate change.

Comment: Just did. I don't see it yet, so I guess it will be reviewed before it gets published.

Comment: This is the enhancement request: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1379
which was closed in favour of this one: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2936

Answer (score 7):

In answer to

> If I update my jdk image (apt-get upgrade for instance), I assume I do not corrupt the dependent images? However, I also assume that the dependency tree is not as you would expect any longer.

I've verified this by updating a dependent image, and checking out the dependencies. What you get is indeed a valid state, but the dependent image is not based on the image you'd naively expect any longer:

[image: docker dependency tree]

Answer (score 0):

I feel using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) can also be helpful in avoiding such pitfalls. It will help you keep single dockerfile per application.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a simple program, CLade, for exactly the same needs as yours.

Take a look around: https://github.com/lesomnus/clade

Your example can be expressed in CLade's `port.yaml` like this:

```yaml
name: registry.hub.docker.com/quintenk/tomcat7
images:
  - tags: ['latest']
    from: registry.hub.docker.com/quintenk/jdk7-oracle:latest
```

However, you need to run the `clade build` command manually, but you can list outdated images via the `clade outdate` command.
I used these commands to automate the build in CI. If interested, see https://github.com/lesomnus/clade/blob/main/.github/workflows/clade-outdated.yaml.